# Input type="file" on Cordova 7, WebView, Android 7.1 only opens file browser directly, cannot choose camera

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, webview

When I try [this demo page](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) in Chrome 60.0.3112.107 on Android 7.1.1 and tap Select File or Drop File, an app chooser comes up which allows me to choose between Camera, Camcorder and File browser. I am unable to achieve similar behaviour in my Ionic v1 app.

I tried following combinations (and many more):

```
<input type="file" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="capture" />
```

but all of them simply open the default file browser directly and do not allow me to choose Camera.

This is my environment:

- Ionic 1.3.3
- Cordova 7.0.1, cordova-android 6.2.3
- Cordova plugins (the relevant ones):

  - cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1
  - cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3
  - cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19
  - cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1
  - cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0
  - cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0
- phone: Android 7.1.1, WebView 60.0.3112.107
- the app has these permissions (in manifest and I also ask for them before use)

  - READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  - WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  - CAMERA

I also tried using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and [cordova-filechooser](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) to no avail.

Is there something I can do to make this work like it works in Chrome or do I need to directly use cordova-plugin-camera if I want to take a photo? Ideally, I'd like to find a cross-platform/cordova solution that works on iOS too without the need of native programming.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any solution for above?

Comment: @PankajDadure unfortunately, I was forced to include two buttons: one for selecting file (utilizing ng-file-upload) and one for taking a photo (using cordova-plugin-camera and its ngCordova wrapper).

Answer (score -1):

Did you looked a [this](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp) repo. 
I used my self it has the ability if you want to create a photo directly with the camera. That should normally work, it has nothing to do with cordova, the code is normal native android code. If you have any other question just ask.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it, but unfortunately I'm not much of a native programmer, so I was hoping for some kind of crossplatform/cordova solution that would work on iOS too. I'll mention that in the question too.

Comment: I am not really into Cordova. I know that does the job. If you have any more questions just ask me.